# How do I build downwards?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Just opened up my previous save game in No Man's Sky (Steam, PC) and it seems like with the latest update and the redesigned build menu, I can no longer build down. Is there a way to do this anymore?

Specifically, I have some bases that are built from a series of small cuboid rooms. My bases appear unchanged, but I can't build any further down than I've already built into the earth. I can build upwards, I can build horizontally, but I can't build down to create new "basement" levels. I've tried both with the regular camera and the build camera, also "free" placement and "grid" placement.

Previously, when I focused on a previously placed room, one of the available grid snap positions was down. Now, it appears to offer to let me build an intersecting room for some reason:

[image: Attempting to build downwards]

... however horizontal placement still seems to work as it used to:

[image: Attempting to build horizontally]

How do I build down? Or am I now stuck with however "deep" I managed to build my bases prior to this update?

I've tried deleting an existing room and rebuilding it, thinking that maybe the "legacy" pre-update rooms might be in some sort of weird state, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Maybe you reached the lowest possible level?

Comment: I doubt it, since if I go up one level, I can't build down from there either.

Comment: I think the base update added a whole new level of bugs. I also noticed problem in placing down cuboid floors in stacked cuboid structures. Not to mention that the new design of the cuboid floor with the red ring is ..... HORRIBLE.

Comment: Temporary, untested fix: go to the lowest level. Place a door on the wall. Use the terrain manipulator to create an hole that goes further down. Place the new cube under the existing one. Use restore mode to remove the tunnel you have just created.

Comment: Not tested in this update, but I always had issues building downwards, every time I reloaded, I'd come back to portions of the base buried underground again

Comment: I stopped having that problem a long time ago. At least with the most recent updates (past 1-2 years) it seems that the terrain edits you make to your base in that regard do persist. Either the Beyond update, or the one immediately before it seem to have fixed that.